# Retrieve array of xml from PostgreSQL in Java

Tags: java, xml, postgresql

In order to retrieve a sample which has an XML field, I use the following code:

```
    String my_call = "CALL my_proc(?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(my_call);
    ps.setSQLXML(1, null);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    rs.next()
    SQLXML desc = rs.getSQLXML(1);
    // use desc
```

And this works perfectly.

But another procedure returns an array of XML. I tried the following code, without success:

```
String my_call = "CALL my_other_proc(?)";
Array xml = connection.createArrayOf("xml", new Object[]{}); // what's wrong here ?
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(my_call);
ps.setArray(1, xml);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
rs.next();
Array xml_array = rs.getArray(1);
SQLXML[] sqlxmls = (SQLXML[])xml_array.getArray(); // what's wrong here ?
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.sql.SQLXML;
```

Answer (score 0):

For arrays, custom types other than `UUID` (via [`ArrayAssistant`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgArray.java#L45)) and `JSONB` (returned as `String`) is currently not supported.

However, you work around that using `String`, e.g.:

```java
Array xml_array = rs.getArray(1);
Object[] sqlxmls = (Object[]) xml_array.getArray();
for (Object o : sqlxmls) {
    PGobject pgValue = PGobject.class.cast(o);
    SQLXML xml = conn.createSQLXML();
    xml.setString(pgValue.getValue());
    StreamSource source = xml.getSource(StreamSource.class);
    // ...
}
```

For further details, have a look at the code of [`PgArray.buildArray(...)`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgArray.java#L537).

This also applies to statement parameters. Instead of using the standard JDBC `SQLXML` objects, just use a `String[]` as the argument, e.g.:

```java
List<String> docs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    docs.add("<test index=\"" + (i + 1) + "\"><property value=\"true\"/></test>");
}

Array docsArray = conn.createArrayOf("XML", docs.toArray());
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO t_array_xml (id, docs) VALUES (?, ?);")) {
    stmt.setInt(1, 1);
    stmt.setArray(2, docsArray);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
docsArray.free();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, is still doesn't work. Now I get this error java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to java.sql.SQLXML. Any ideas ?

Comment: You are right, sorry. I just had to dig deeper into the code to actually figure out what happens. basic thing is that the `PgSQLXML` implementation does not extend `PGObject` and if you use it to store data, you'll end up with the standard `Object.toString()` result in the database instead of the actual XML. For reading data it is the same as there is no support (yet - thinking about contributing it now) for automatic conversion either which implies you'll end up with standard `PGObject` with `String` value.